# Solving equation for a parallel capacitor

Tags: equation-solving

I am a beginner at Mathematica and am trying to solve a simple equation.

[image: parallel capacitor]

There are multiple ways to solve this and I am trying to solve this using charge conservation.

```
Cpareq1 = C1 == Q1 * V
Cpareq2 = C2 == Q2 * V
Cpareq3 = Qpar == Q1 + Q2
Cpareq4 = Cpar * V == Qpar
```

If I would try to solve this by hand I would do:

```
Q1 = C1 * V
Q2 = C2 * V
// Insert [1] and [2] into [3]
Qpar = C1 * V + C2 * V
Qpar = (C1 + C2) * V
// Insert [3] into [4]
Cpar * V = (C1 + C2) * V
Cpar = C1 + C2
```

So far I have tried using `Solve` but it just doesn't do what I expect it to.

```
Solve[{Cpareq1, Cpareq2, Cpareq3, Cpareq4}, {Cpar, C1, C2}]
Out = {}
Solve[{Cpareq1, Cpareq2, Cpareq3, Cpareq4}, {Cpar, Qpar, C1, C2}]
Out = {{Cpar -> -((-Q1 - Q2)/V), Qpar -> Q1 + Q2, C1 -> Q1 V, C2 -> Q2 V}}
```

How do I tell Mathematica that I want it to take my set of equations, solve it for Cpar and eliminate everything but C1 and C2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to solve for Q1, Q2 instead of C1, C2, because Q1, Q2 are the unknown and C1, C2 are parameter. You also want to use the correct equations for the capacitances C1, C2:

```
Cpareq1 := C1*V == Q1
Cpareq2 := C2*V == Q2
Cpareq3 := Qpar == Q1 + Q2
Cpareq4 := Cpar*V == Qpar

Solve[{Cpareq1, Cpareq2, Cpareq3, Cpareq4}, {Cpar, Qpar, Q1, Q2}]
{{Cpar -> C1 + C2, Qpar -> C1 V + C2 V, Q1 -> C1 V, Q2 -> C2 V}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to eliminate certain variables, you may also find it useful to use the function Eliminate:

```
Cpareq1 = C1*V == Q1
Cpareq2 = C2*V == Q2
Cpareq3 = Qpar == Q1 + Q2
Cpareq4 = Cpar*V == Qpar

Eliminate[Cpareq1 && Cpareq2 && Cpareq3 && Cpareq4, {Qpar, Q1, Q2}]
(-C2 + Cpar) V == C1 V

Solve[%, Cpar]
{{Cpar -> C1 + C2}}
```